# how to print variable from node.js to html

Tags: node.js

im trying to get random file from text file and print out in my html. Im getting the line successfully in my console  , however its not displaying on the screen for some reason even though i passed the variable in the routesjs file. any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var line;

function read(file, callback) {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        var lines = data.split("\n");

 //Random item number
 var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);

 //Get random line
 var line = lines[r];

    console.log(line);


    });
}

var output = read('Input.txt', function(data) {

    var lines = data.split("/n");

    //Random item number
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);

    //Get random line
    var line = lines[r];
    console.log("d;d;");

});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {page:'Home', menuId:'home', line: line});
});

router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('about', {page:'About Us', menuId:'about'});
});

router.get('/contact', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('contact', {page:'Contact Us', menuId:'contact'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

views/index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <% include partials/head %>
</head>
<body>
<% include partials/menu %>

<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
  <h3><%= page %></h3><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
       // not printing anything 
      <p>your account info : <%= line %> </p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
<% include partials/script %>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var line = lines[r];` is a function local variable different from outer `var line;`.

try `line = lines[r];`.

But, I think that it is better to call read() and get lines in `function(req, res, next) {` locally.

*Add:* If you want to read file synchronously, you should use `readFileSync`.